# What is Client Payload Data Limit for LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was playing with LWC and was checking limits. I could not find what the max client-side payload limit like the way we had in [Aura](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_client_data_limit.htm).

Aura had 1MB limit which was increased to 4MB recently. Anyone has idea whats client payload limit for lwc?

Comment: There's no specific mention of the limits on the documentation at least. Seems to be a candidate to get confirmation directly from Salesforce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LWC is limited to the same 4MB payload limit.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, its good to see SF devs / Architects helping here on SFSE.

Comment: Hi Kevin - Is there any specific error/exception that is received if payload size is exceeded?

Comment: Received exception event aura:systemError from server