# How to upload larger size file using input tag of type html in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, files, fileupload

I have implemented custom file upload component using input file html tag and rendering it as browse file button.

The issue with component is:-

- When trying to upload file more than 4 mb of size, i am getting
     below error:-

> [AuraClientInputException from server] Unexpected request input.
>   Expected input format:  "Max message parameter length is 4194304
>   characters.".

It seems apex heap size error.

**How i am reading the file uploaded?**

I am using the FileReader Api to read it and fire an apex method to save the file as ContentVersion Object record in Salesforce.

```
this.fileReader = new FileReader();
            // set onload function of FileReader object  
            this.fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
                this.filecontent = this.fileReader.result;
                let base64 = 'base64,';
                this.content = this.filecontent.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
                this.filecontent = this.filecontent.substring(this.content);
                //saving the file by calling an apex method
                saveTheFile({
                    parentId: 'a8pq00000001w4QAAQ', fileName: this.fileName,
                    base64Data: encodeURIComponent(this.filecontent)
                }).then(result => {
                    window.console.log('result ====> ' + result);
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Showing errors if any while inserting the files
                        window.console.log(error);
                    });
            });
            this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
```

**Why i can't use Lightning FileUpload component?**

This component uploads the document as soon user select the file in browse window,but our aim is to upload files only when we
 click a specific upload button.
 It also does not have maximum file size attribute.

Comment: This is a limitation of the size of a request an Apex @AuraEnabled method can handle. If you are looking to upload a larger file size, you may have to implement something using the Chatter REST API which supports file sizes up to 2GB. You may want to look at this GitHub repository https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-lightning-api-component

Comment: The max content limit for AURA or lwc is 4MB:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/264604/19118

You have to use lightning:fileUpload or call rest API's directly from JS

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to implement workarounds as of now if you need custom functionality w.r.t uploading files.

The max content limit for AuraEnabled methods as mentioned by Pranay Jaiswal is 4MB, which is also reduced when it is encoded into base64 and gives you a final size limit around 1.5 -2 MB that you'll be able to upload.

One of the workarounds would involve implement using Chatter Rest API and it will support file sizes upto 2GB as mentioned by Bryan Anderson.

Here's what I got for this question, I recently had one such requirement which needed upto 30MB of files to be uploaded using input(type=file). Using AuraEnabled was out of question and I didn't really have time to implement a solution using Chatter Rest API. So, I implemented this:

The solution involves using The AJAX toolkit & a Visualforce Page which helped me overcome the API enabled Session issue withing lightning context.

The html file:

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-hide">
        <iframe src="/apex/uploadHelper"></iframe>
    </div>

    <lightning-input type="file" label="Attachment" onchange={handleFilesChange}> 
    </lightning-input>
        
     <button onclick={fireToVF}> fire</button>
</template>
```

The JS controller:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ApiConnector extends LightningElement {
    recordid = '<parent record id>';

    connectedCallback(){
        window.addEventListener('message', (message)=>{
            console.log(message.data);
        });
    }

    toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
            let result = reader.result;
            let base64 = 'base64,';
            let content = result.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
            let fileContents = result.substring(content);
            resolve(fileContents);
        }
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });

    async handleFilesChange(event){
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.file = {
                parentRec : this.recordid,
                fileName : event.target.files[0].name,
                fileContent : await this.toBase64(event.target.files[0])
            }
        }
    }

    fireToVF(){
        this.fireToComponent(this.file);
    }

    fireToComponent(message){
        this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
    }
}
```

The Visualforce Page within iframe:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
    
    <script type="text/javascript">__sfdcSessionId = '{!$Api.Session_Id}';</script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script>
    function uploadContentVersion(recordId ,filename, filecontent) {
        var contentVersion = new sforce.SObject('ContentVersion');
        
        contentVersion.Title = filename;
        contentVersion.PathOnClient = '/' + filename;
        contentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId = recordId;
        contentVersion.VersionData = filecontent;
        
        var results = sforce.connection.create([contentVersion]);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].getBoolean("success")) {
                alert('New ContentVersion record created:' + results[i].id);
            }
            else {
                alert('Failed:' + results[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('message', (message)=>{
        console.log(message.data);
        var file = message.data;
        uploadContentVersion(file.parentRec, file.fileName , file.fileContent);
    });
        
    window.parent.postMessage('loaded', "*")
    </script>
    
    <body></body>
</apex:page>
```

Note that this is just an example and may not practice the security requirements required for PostMessage API(checks for Origin and Source).

Since the AJAX toolkit uses SOAP API internally, it has a max limit of 50MB, which due to Base64 Encoding will be reduced from 30-35MB depending on the content in the document.

I had also tried getting the API enabled sessionId from Visualforce page and hitting the Rest api directly from LWC, but the POST fetch request returned 302 and redirected the browser to make a GET request, I'm curious if SF allows POST method over Rest API from LWC/Lightning Context.

Comment: To use the REST Api within LWC, add self org URL to CORS settings and that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an app native in salesforce which can upload large files and handle mass uploads with efficient batching. https://github.com/ManinderSfdc/SalesforceDoculoader

Note: It uses the sessionId from a VFpage which is passed from apex to LWC to call Salesforce API directly from client. So, avoid using this app for community which might pose a security risk. But I feel using it for salesforce users it is safe. That is what we are using it for.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.